# MySQL root password does not work in Windows

Tags: mysql, windows, passwords, root

I have tried all of the other solutions on this site.. they all seem to be the same anyway.

1. Kill server via Task Manager, then restart it using the `./mysqld --skip-grant-tables` option.
2. `PS C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin> ./mysqld --init-file='C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysql-init.txt'`

   mysql-init.txt:

   ```
   UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('root') WHERE User='root';
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   ```
3. Restart the mysqld
4. `PS C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin> ./mysql --user=root -p`

   ```
   Enter password: ****
   ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
   ```

I can access the server with `--safe --skip-grant-tables` enabled, but that does not do me any good as changing the password there changes it in the tables for sure, however it does not allow me to log in just the same.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

---

Edit:

Attempted the same procedure with following changes:

1. Kill server via Task Manager, then restart it using the `./mysqld --skip-grant-tables` option.
2. `PS C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin> ./mysqld --init-file='C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\bin\\mysql-init.txt'`
3. Start mysqld
4. `PS C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin> ./mysql --user=root -p`

   `Enter password: ****`
   `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Note: I tried this solution with and without the `./mysqld --skip-grant-tables` option.

Is there some other error that I could be making or something that is a possible cause this procedure is not working. I heard something about making sure the innodb tables directory was correct.... but I cannot find more information on that. Additionally my install did not include ODBC Connector as I did not have the proper software installed for it.

---

Edit2:

`./mysqld --skip-grant-tables`

`./mysql -u root -p`
`Enter password: ****`

~

`mysql> select * from user where user='root'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                  Host: %
                  User: root
              Password: *81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B
           Select_priv: Y
           Insert_priv: Y
           Update_priv: Y
           Delete_priv: Y
           Create_priv: Y
             Drop_priv: Y
           Reload_priv: Y
         Shutdown_priv: Y
          Process_priv: Y
             File_priv: Y
            Grant_priv: Y
       References_priv: Y
            Index_priv: Y
            Alter_priv: Y
          Show_db_priv: Y
            Super_priv: Y
 Create_tmp_table_priv: Y
      Lock_tables_priv: Y
          Execute_priv: Y
       Repl_slave_priv: Y
      Repl_client_priv: Y
      Create_view_priv: Y
        Show_view_priv: Y
   Create_routine_priv: Y
    Alter_routine_priv: Y
      Create_user_priv: Y
            Event_priv: Y
          Trigger_priv: Y
Create_tablespace_priv: Y
              ssl_type:
            ssl_cipher:
           x509_issuer:
          x509_subject:
         max_questions: 0
           max_updates: 0
       max_connections: 0
  max_user_connections: 0
                plugin:
 authentication_string:
      password_expired: N
1 row in set (0.00 sec)`

Comment: Don't forget to double encode slashes (e.g. `--init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt`).

Comment: Stop mysqld

PS C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin> ./mysqld --init-file='C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\bin\\mysql-init.txt'

Start mysqld

PS C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin> ./mysql --user=root -p
Enter password: ****
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Is there some other error that I could be making or something that is a possible cause this is not working. I heard something about the innodb tables directory.... but I cannot find more information on that. 

Additionally my install did not include odbc.

Comment: sorry formatting doesn't seem to work well in the comment section.

Comment: Edit your question to include the extra info. ;-)

Comment: Added the new info to the question under the 'Edit:' heading.

Comment: Is there definitely a `root` user?

Comment: User account does exist with all privileges. The encrypted password is root.

Comment: Can you add the output of a select from user to your question?

Comment: added the output of the select command to the 'Edit2:' header.

Comment: The `mysqladmin` tool should be able to this correctly. Running a query to do it seems out of the ordinary.

Comment: @tadman In regards to this I agree, however I can get the password to change, I can even flush the privileges.  I can verify this by running these commands in `--skip-grant-tables` mode.

the issue that is preventing me from accessing the root account almost seems to be as if root is either blocked, or the grant tables are incorrect/loading incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone, I have solved the issue and have updated the question with the full details.

Comment: Glad you've solved it. Paste your answer into the answer box then it'll be marked as solved. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved:

I had previously installed MySQL once before on this machine, unfortunately it seems it was never fully uninstalled and... I would assume the previous grant-tables were interfering with the installation. I fully removed everything in regards to MySQL and reinstalled it. It seems to be working fine for the time being. I will be attempting to change the password soon in order to make sure.... I changed the password and it worked as expected this time.

Lesson learned = Make sure to delete everything from previous installations. Do not just trust the installer to remove everything

Comment: Often the installer doesn't remove everything since that could lead to a catastrophic data loss if you did it by mistake. Good notes here.

Comment: Seconded. A complete wipe and reinstall did it for me too. (Lucky I make daily SQL dumps as backup!)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar issue right after I had installed MySQL Server 8.0 on Windows 11 via the MySQL Installer.

The main problem was that the password I set for my root user during the installation contained invalid characters, and the password I also set for the other users I created during the installation contained invalid characters.

I fixed the issue by completely deleting and re-installing MySQL Server from scratch.

During the installation, I entered a simple password for the root user that only contained alpha-numeric characters and also avoided creating any additional users aside the root user.

This did the trick for me, as I was able to connect to the server right afterwards using the username "root" and the password I set during the installation.